# How to filestream strings(including spaces)?

Tags: c++, string, filestream

I have an existing text file called database.txt. If I try to add a string at the end that contains a space, it only adds the string content until the space. How can I add the whole string input, including the spaces?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string line;
fstream  database;    
database.open("Database.txt",ios::app);
cout<<"Name";
cin>>line;
database<<line;
database.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: Change `cin>>line;` to `std::getline(cin,line);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `std::cin >> line;` try use `std::getline(std::cin,line);`